# jQuery Positioning and Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a piece of code:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent) {
parent = this.parent();
this.css({
"position": "absolute",
"top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
"left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
});
return this;
}
```

This code grabs an element and moves it to the center of the parent. Works nicely. There are a couple of things I would like it to do aside of what it's doing.

1. I need it to float above all other elements in that parent. A z index more or less. I tried to apply a z-index, but it didn't seem to work. I dunno if I may have been doing it wrong, or if there is a better way.
2. I need it to move back to the position it was in. The way this works, is the block is gonna be positioned on the page (via CSS), and when the user clicks, it moves it to the center of the page, as the code is already doing. Is there any way that, if a user clicks an exit button, I can program said button to move it back to where it originally was? i don't know if I can pass variables around in jQuery.
3. This option is more for aesthetics, and i don't deem it necessary, but would like it if you have a little extra time. I would like the block to slide from it's position to the center of the page, and back, as opposed to just popping there. As I stated, this is just aesthetics and i really don't need that to happen.

Much appreciated to anyone that can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to implement a similar requirement but It should have all the features that you were looking for. Try [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Y2XUW/1/)

> I need it to float above all other elements in that parent. A z index
>   more or less. I tried to apply a z-index, but it didn't seem to work.
>   I dunno if I may have been doing it wrong, or if there is a better
>   way.

I always use z-index in range of 1001 or greater for such cases. Even in the demo, it works fine. Try this and let us know if you still not working for you.

> I need it to move back to the position it was in. The way this works,
>   is the block is gonna be positioned on the page (via CSS), and when
>   the user clicks, it moves it to the center of the page, as the code is
>   already doing. Is there any way that, if a user clicks an exit button,
>   I can program said button to move it back to where it originally was?
>   i don't know if I can pass variables around in jQuery.

I stored the original position of the element using `.data` API and restored it back to its original position when close(exit) button is clicked.

> This option is more for aesthetics, and i don't deem it necessary, but
>   would like it if you have a little extra time. I would like the block
>   to slide from it's position to the center of the page, and back, as
>   opposed to just popping there. As I stated, this is just aesthetics
>   and i really don't need that to happen.

You can use `.animate` instead of CSS which will transcend the element from it original position to the destination position in specified time.

Comment: I attempted this on my own. I made a couple of changes to suit my needs, but I'm not getting anything. I posted a link in Nick's comment below if you'd like to have a look.

Comment: @JerryRay Where do I need to look in that code? Your code in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/skram/DCvNW/

Comment: It starts at comment // Replace shrimp image with content in the jQuery. You may also wanna look over the showTips and hideTips functions.

Comment: But notice it's not centering it. The function isn't doing anything, and at this point I don't know if it's a javascript or CSS problem. It fires off when you click the box that is supposed to have an image in it.

Comment: @JerryRay You need to add `this.css('position', 'absolute');` inside showTips and set it to normal when you use hideTips. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/DCvNW/1/

Comment: I understand. Because we set the top and the left, the position had to be set to absolute which was never done. The only other thing I can think of, is when the block moves out of place, the block under it moves up. Can we prevent that? Also, if I wanted to assign this function to another block, would I have to set this one back to a relative position when it moves back? Thank you very much, good sir.

Comment: @JerryRay When a block element is moved from its position, other elements in the same level will reposition to fill its place. There are few trick you can try to avoid such cases.. like adding a empty container wrapping the section and move the section leaving the container intact.. Make sure the container width and height are properly set so that it doesn't shrink once the content is gone.

Comment: Alright. And we're running into another problem. gahh. probably something simple. Remember when I asked you how to stop that other block from running up? Well when I program the function to move it back into place, it moves back, but doesn't stay there. It pops back to the middle. The only thing I added to the hide function was `"width": this.data('cur-width') + 'px',` to preserve the width and `"height": this.data('cur-height') + 'px'` To preserve the height. i did set those variables in the show function. thanks.

Comment: @DaGeneral Please posrt a new question. This question has already been answered.. I am out for tonight, will try to check tomorrow. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to float above all other elements, you're right in that you'll need to use z-index for that, but you'll need to make sure that each element is positioned and each element has a `z-index` value to start with, including the parent. The parent will also need to be positioned.

In order to revert back to their original positions, you'll have to grab their current `left` and `top` offsets. In your `click` event listener, move the element back to its old position.

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent) {
  var oldTop = this.css('top');
  var oldLeft = this.css('left');
  parent = this.parent();
  this.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
    "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
  });
  this.click(function(e) {
    this.css('top', oldTop);
    this.css('left', oldLeft);
  });
  return this;
}
```

In order to do the animation (instead of just jumping to the position), you can animate the `left` and `top` values using jQuery.

```
this.animate({
  'top': ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
  'left': ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
});
```

**EDIT** You may want to consider using `this.offset()`. This returns an object containing the methods `left` and `top`.

```
var offset = this.offset();
var oldTop = offset.top;
var oldLeft = offset.left;
```

Comment: Alright. So every div block will have to be positioned. Considering I have them manually positioned with CSS, can i just set a relative positioning? If I understand that will not change the way they are layed out.

Comment: You can place absolutely positioned elements within a relatively positioned parent. In a relative:relative relationship, the elements will still interact with each other. In a relative:absolute, they will not.

Comment: It would probably just be easier for me to show you what I have. referring to what was posted above. I implemented the code, and made changes as necessary, but the box isn't re positioning. it does everything else. The jQuery for this box starts at comment // Replace shrimp image with content. http://pastie.org/3757467